# Converting SQL data type BIT NOT NULL to C# type Byte through a SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a simple piece of code

```
bool retrievalAttempted = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetByte(1));
```

where column `1` is of type `BIT NOT NULL` and yet I keep getting the exception

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `bit` type corresponds to a boolean, not a byte

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a `bit`-column you have to use `reader.GetBoolean`:

```
bool retrievalAttempted = reader.GetBoolean(1);
```

[SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
bit       Boolean       Bit       GetSqlBoolean       Boolean       GetBoolean
```

`GetByte` is only used for `tinyint`-columns.

Answer (score 0):

A bit is different than a byte !

Look at this link for sql server types vs .net types [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx)